# NodeJS OSX error building node-sass

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am running OSX 10.11.1 and trying to `npm install` a project that contains a node-sass dependency in the package.json:

"dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2"
  }

I am running NPM version 2.14.7 and node version 4.2.3.  When I run `npm install` or npm `rebuild node-sass` I get the following error output:

```
> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall /Users/markroper/code/mktg/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
gyp: /Users/markroper/.node-gyp/4.2.3/common.gypi not found (cwd: /Users/markroper/code/mktg/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/markroper/code/mktg/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/lib/configure.js:346:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/markroper/code/mktg/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/markroper/code/mktg/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! pangyp -v v2.3.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
```

Has anyone worked around this error with these versions?

Comment: I reverted back to version `12.22.1` for node and version `6.14.12` for npm and `node-sass` installed correctly. Follow this [link](https://katopz.medium.com/how-to-install-specific-nodejs-version-c6e1cec8aa11) for help reverting back to older versions of node using `homebrew`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add --unsafe-perm flag while installing

For linux/mac

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

For windows environment , hit same command removing sudo

Answer (score 12):

Node-sass doesn't work well with newer node versions.
You can work around this problem by (temporarily) downgrading your node version while installing node-sass with `npm install`.

I recommend using Node Version Manager (nvm) for this, installation instructions can be found on [Github](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). After installing nvm, you are able to do `nvm install v0.12.7` You can verify the node version running with `node -v` If this returns v0.12.7, you should be able run npm install. (make sure this is done is the same terminal window)

Answer (score 2):

`node-sass` is now a deprecated package. It is best to avoid using it and install `sass` package instead.

```
npm install sass
```

It works fine on latest versions of Node and npm and it's a distribution of Dart Sass, which is currently a recommended implementation.